# How to "unshard" an existant collection in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

While setting up some collections in a mongo database to be sharded, I entered the name of one of them wrong (typo letter at the end).

When I do db.printShardingStatus(), I see that inexistent collection sitting there and looking dumb. How can I remove it from my sharding config without breaking anything.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [page on removeshard](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/removeshard+command) for the details, but

`db.runCommand({"removeshard" : "server:port"});`is what you're looking for.